# DateTime compare issues with InflateColumn::DateTime

Tags: perl, datetime, catalyst, dbix-class

I am having trouble comparing [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) objects in my [Catalylst](http://www.catalystframework.org/). I have an end_date column which is being inflated by [DBIx::Class::InflateColumn::DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::InflateColumn::DateTime), and I am inflating it with my timezone:

```
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
    end_date => { data_type => 'datetime', time_zone => 'America/Chicago' },
);
```

I have a function that is supposed to tell me if my event has closed or not, this is defined in my Schema for this class:

```
sub closed { 
    my ($self) = @_; 
    my $now = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'America/Chicago');
    warn DateTime->compare($now, $self->end_date);
    warn $now;
    warn $self->end_date;
    return DateTime->compare($now, $self->end_date) == 1;
}
```

However, it is not working properly. It is telling me that events have closed before they actually have. Here is an example output from the warns:

```
1
2014-06-29T12:20:48
2014-06-29T12:20:50
```

As you can see, it is saying that the first date is greater than end_date, even though it is not. I haven't been able to figure out why this is. However, whenever I convert them and create new DateTime objects:

```
sub closed { 
    my ($self) = @_; 
    my $now = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime(DateTime->now(time_zone => 'America/Chicago'));
    my $end_date = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime($self->end_date);
    return DateTime->compare($now, $end_date) == 1;
}
```

Then they compare correctly, and compare returns -1. Does anyone know why this could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debugging information is useless since you didn't include the time zone offsets (e.g. by using `->strftime('%FT%T%z')`). If you did, I bet you'll find the first date is indeed greater than the end date, and I bet it's using UTC for your inflated column.

Looking at the docs, the time zone is to be provided by the `timezone` attribute, but you used `time_zone`.

```
{ data_type => 'datetime', timezone => "America/Chicago", locale => "de_DE" }
```

(That was a poor, confusing choice on D::C::IC::DT's behalf.)

Comment: Thanks. You were right, it was not being inflated to the same timezone. So when I save it into the database, it is my database settings that will determine the timezone for a string such as `2014-06-29 12:20:48`, right? Because now when it is being converted, it's actually being converted to the wrong time for my current timezone.